# Java Writing to Properties File Not Working

Tags: java, properties-file

For some reason, the following code, which in my program is surrounded by a try-catch statement, is not working, as it continues to throw a NumberFormatException, 
 and also wipes the properties file clean of information. Help is appreciated.

```
        File propFile = new File("path\to\file\properties.properties");
        FileOutputStream outStream  = new FileOutputStream(propFile);
        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(propFile);

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(inStream);

        out.println(prop.getProperty("entryID"));

        prop.setProperty("entryID", Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("entryID"))+1));

        prop.store(outStream, "");
```

Comment: `out` is a PrintWriter object passed to function containing above code by the way.

Comment: What is the printing result?

Comment: The content of the properties-file would most likely show what the issue is. My guess would be that the properties-file is malformed. The output will be cleared by the `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: It should be 0 for the first execution of the code, and then it increases by one for each execution

Comment: All i put in the file was `entryID=0`

Comment: `FileOutputStream outStream  = new FileOutputStream(propFile);` clears the `propFile`, because that constructor *truncates*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change line of sequence, You are creating FileOutStream Object before you read the content

Please find attached working snippet

File propFile = new File("path\to\file\properties.properties");

```
    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(propFile);

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(inStream);

    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("entryID"));

    prop.setProperty("entryID", Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("entryID"))+1));
    FileOutputStream outStream  = new FileOutputStream(propFile);
    prop.store(outStream, "");
```